# python subprocess command not found

Tags: python-3.x, shell, path, subprocess

RHEL7 I notice that trying to run any command that "should" be in the environment fails, but running commands with relative or absolute paths succeeds.

I suppose I can manually translate all of those cals to shell functions to `/bin/whatever` but it would be nice if there was a way to run the subprocess from python without having to do that.  Is there some setup parameter in `subprocess` that I'm missing?

Here's a bunch of failing cases:

```
me@server~ python3 --version
Python 3.6.6
me@server~ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Aug 27 2018, 10:45:14)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run('ls')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/l/python3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/l/python3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/l/python3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ls': 'ls'
>>> subprocess.run('ls', shell=True)
/bin/sh: ls: command not found
CompletedProcess(args='ls', returncode=127)
>>> subprocess.run(['ls'], shell=True)
/bin/sh: ls: command not found
CompletedProcess(args=['ls'], returncode=127)
>>> subprocess.run(['ls'], shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
/bin/bash: ls: command not found
CompletedProcess(args=['ls'], returncode=127)
```

Here's one that succeeds:

```
>>> run('/bin/ls')
bin       ld.script.arm-bbb   ld.script.x86-galileo  Makedefs          make-errs  platform-cmake  uboot-tool  xinu      xinu.boot  xinu.x86.boot
binaries  ld.script.arm-qemu  ld.script.x86-qemu     Makedefs.EXAMPLE  Makefile   qex.exp         version     xinu.bin  xinu.map
CompletedProcess(args='/bin/ls', returncode=0)
```

Here's the system I'm ssh'd into:

```
me@server~ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-ia32:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-ia32:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
Release:        7.7
Codename:       Maipo
```

Comment: You somehow disturbed the value of `PATH` before you started Python, so that it no longer contains`/bin`. Fix that, rather than worrying about your Python code.

Comment: Well.  I am surprised that none of the other commands I've been running (for months!) have encountered this issue, but you're exactly right.  `/usr/bin/` was on my  `PATH` but not `/bin`

Comment: @chepner how would you do this?